# Tomcat HTTP 404 error

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc

I use `Apache Tomcat/7.0.42` with `Spring MVC` and sometimes I got `HTTP 404 error`.
So I have to restart `Tomcat` and it's work.
Where this issue come from ?

I afraid this problem occurs when I will finally deploy my web application .

Comment: Youssef, too vague please provide more infos: log files, application log, architecture, AJP connector, datasources ... check the memory heap

Comment: it doesn't display no log when this issue occurs ! how can i check the memory heap ? is this important because i got also sometimes `PermGen space`

Comment: There are severla tools: jvisualvm, jconsol or jstat -gc PID <intervall> or put on java options "-Xloggc:gc.log -XX:-PrintGCDetails"

Comment: i don't get it but i will take a look on these tools.

Comment: look on the java home directory...bin directory

Comment: but why ? what is the relation with my problem !!

Comment: 404 could happen when tomcat undeploy application due to low heap space or shutdown executors...but generally speaking it seems a DOS...

Comment: so how can i figured out where the issue come from ? and how to increase memory ?

Comment: too many possibilities, but firstly tune the memory ...http://javamaster.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/apache-tomcat-tuning-guide/  .. -Xmx1024m –Xms1024m -XX:MaxNewSize=384m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Comment: thanks @venergiac i will try this i comeback.